# Ionic - Videogular Fullscreen and Android

Tags: android, fullscreen, videogular

again I got a really strange Bug on Android devices for my app with the use of videogular.

I also use a Fullscreen-Plugin, and a plugin for Screen-Orientation to make sure which orientation is in use.

But anyway, the problem now is, that when I play a video and change to "FullScreen"-Mode, go to landscape-mode, and then cancel the Fullscreen-Mode I see my app in the "Ultimate Zoom-Mode" (not real, I only call it in that way). Which means everything is too big and in fact I only see the upper left corner of my app.

That is kind of a strange thing. And I have no idea where it comes from or what I can do against it.

First I fixed the issue by change to landscape mode when the user go to fullscreen. But now I found out, when the user click on the "Hardware-Back-Button" instead of the "Cancel Fullscreen"-Button on the screen, the "Ultimate Zoom..." returns.

Does anybody have an idea what I can do against it?

Thank you, and sorry for the long post.